# Use table data to substitute into a function

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, programming

If I have the following function

```
Rx = Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] + Subscript[x, 3] - Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3]
```

[image]

I want to add it as a column in the following table where it uses the data of the table and gives the output
[image]

My attempt after using one of the answers here is as follows

```
lear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

(data1 = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]) // MatrixForm;
(table = Prepend[
    Transpose@
     Join[{Range@Length@data1}, 
      Transpose@
       data1, {data1[[All, 1]] + data1[[All, 3]]}, {data1[[All, 2]]}],
     Flatten[{"order", Subscript["x", #] & /@ Range[3], 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(1\)]\)=\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(1\)]\)+\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(2\)]\)=\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)]\)", Rx}]]) // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

What is required is to find the outputs of the function in the table where the table data is substituted in the above function

[image]

Please Help

Comment: Perhaps add `{Block[{Subscript},
  Do[Subscript[x, j] = Transpose[data1][[j]], {j, 3}];
  Rx
  ]}` to generate the last table-data column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rx = data1[[All, 1]] data1[[All, 2]] + data1[[All, 3]] - 
  data1[[All, 1]] data1[[All, 2]] data1[[All, 3]]

(table = 
   Prepend[Transpose@
     Join[{Range@Length@data1}, 
      Transpose@
       data1, {data1[[All, 1]] + 
        data1[[All, 3]]}, {data1[[All, 2]]}, {rx}], 
    Flatten[{"order", Subscript["x", #] & /@ Range[3], 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(1\)]\)=\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(1\)]\)+\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(2\)]\)=\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)]\)", Rx}]]) // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]